# How to know which shape should be rendered first?

Tags: matrix, rendering, polygon, shapes, vertex

**Question**
I have two sets of vertices resembling a quad as a 2D array like so:

```
[
    [-4.88962039, 18.43587572,  1.10004488],
    [ 4.99465568, 18.43587572, -0.4146093 ],
    [ 4.93547185, 20.39600888, -0.80245834],
    [-4.95210159, 20.39600888,  0.69246779]
]
```

and

```
 [
     [ -2.12081944, -23.4222632 ,   5.67007155],
     [  3.79729916, -23.4222632 ,   4.71466919],
     [ 2.28690041, 23.62093253, -4.69804563],
     [-3.63408501, 23.62093253, -3.75432715]
]
```

How do I programatically calculate which one should be rendered first? I am going to use the orthogonal projection matrix, so 3D is going to be converted into 2D as a last step.

**What I have tried so far**
I have computed the centroid of the squares and compared their z-values. Although this works for basic shapes like a cube, it didn't work on a more complex poly structure like the vertices above. I have also tried averaging the values, but that didn't work either.
If someone would be able to provide a simple answer (preferably with some pseudocode), it would be greatly appreciated.